# Dwarf Fortress Fullscreen

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I am using the latest version of Dwarf Fortress 0.31.25 and while not exactly a newb (comming back after a long time away) I can't remember how to toggle between Fullscreen and Windowed mode in Dwarf Fortress?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hit <kbd>F11</kbd> and that should do it!

Comment: Perfect! That worked great.